# Solve for two unknown variables and two functions

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Two functions with different definition.

```
 funcA:
    a = a - 2;
    b = b - 1;

 funcB: 
    a = a - 1;
    b = b - 2;
```

Our aim to get the number of operations when *both* `a = 0` *and* `b = 0`;

Sample input: `a = 4, b = 2`

```
  call funcA:
     a become 2, b become 1;
  again call funcA
     a become 0, b become 0;
```

total no of operation performed `2 + 0 = 2` so returned **2**;

Sample input 2: `a = 3, b = 3`

```
  call funcA:
     a become 1, b become 2;
  call funcB
     a become 0, b become 0;
```

total no of operation performed `1 + 1 = 2` so returned **2**;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from special cases:

- if `a < 0` or `b < 0` we have *no solution*
- if `a = 0` and `b <> 0` or `a <> 0` and `b = 0` we have *no solution*
- if `a > 2 * b` or `b > 2 * a` we have *no solution*

If we use `funcA` `x` times and `funcB` `y` times and get `0` from *both* `a` and `b` we can write

```
a - 2 * x - y = 0
b - 2 * y - x = 0
```

Let's solve this system of linear equations for `x` and `y`:

```
2 * x + y = a
2 * y + x = b
```

The solution is

```
x = (2 * a - b) / 3
y = (2 * b - a) / 3
```

So if we have an *integer* solution for `x` and `y` we should perform `funcA` `x` times, `funcB` `y` times

**Code (Java):**

```
public static int Solve(int a, int b) {
  // beware integer overflow! we use long in case a = 2_000_000_000 provided 
  long x = (2L * a - b) / 3;
  long y = (2L * b - a) / 3;

  return ((x >= 0 && y >= 0 && (2L * b - a) % 3 == 0 && (2L * a - b) % 3 == 0))
    ? (int)(x + y)
    : -1; // impossible
}
```

As one can see, we have a direct solution with `O(1)` time and space complexity; there's no need in *dynamic programming*

Comment: @Alex Rudenko: thank you! You are quite right, my bad - the problem is symmetric one it was easy to erroneously swap `x` and `y`

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Bychenko . Solution has passed all the test cases.